# Android SSL - CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android, ssl, tomcat7

My HTTPS service is hosted in TomCat (.keystore created with the help of keytool in JDK bin).

Server certificate is self signed & made it as trusted by installing it in Trusted Root Authorities .

I am able to access the service from browser, but unable to do the same from Android. I am a beginner in J2EE.

[image]

**host.cert** (placed in assets dir) is created with OpenSSL.

I am using the code snippet from Android Developers site

```
        try {
            // Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt

            InputStream inn=getAssets().open("host.cert");

            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(inn);
                Log.i("TEST","ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                inn.close();
            }

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
            URL url = new URL("https://192.168.56.1:8443/RestHTTPS/JavaCodeGeeks/AuthorService/authors/");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            byte arr[]=new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(arr);

            String str=new String(arr);
            Log.i("TEST",str);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("TEST",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I know this is already asked question, but I am unable find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post the solution , for somebody still facing the issue.

**Mainly note 3 things (This is already stated in [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html))**

- Create custom Trust Manager to bypass default Trust Manager.
- Manually verify that the host name is an acceptable.
- Never use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" for testing purposes , instead use your PC's IP address.

Here is the complete code

```
try {

            // Things to Note 1 : Bypass default Trust Managers
            TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                }
            }};

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream inn = getAssets().open("keystore.cer");
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(inn);
                Log.i("TEST", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                inn.close();
            }


            String keyStoreType = "BKS";
            KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, byPassTrustManagers, null);

            // Things to Note 2 : Don't use "localhost" ,instead use IP
            URL url = new URL("https://192.168.56.1:8443/RestHTTPS/JavaCodeGeeks/AuthorService/authors");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                    (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

            // Things to Note 3 : Allow all host
            urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            Log.i("TEST", urlConnection.getResponseMessage() + "");

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            String str = "";
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                str += current;
            }

            Log.i("TEST", "" + str);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TEST", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```